# What directory should I use for the user apache?

Tags: apache-httpd, useradd

I have installed apache from the source with:`prefix=/usr` `sysconfdir=/etc/httpd/` `localstatedir=/var`.

```
useradd -g apache -d /usr/apache -s /sbin/nologin apache
```

Comment: When installing things from source, generally you should use a prefix of `/usr/local`, to keep things separate from software provided by your OS.

Comment: Yes, I know. This is a test, I am learning how to make distribution packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wonder about the **home** directory, it should not matter that much, because it will probably not change the behavior of apache at all.

On Debian, the default homedir for the user running apache is `/var/www` (which is the default `DocumentRoot`).

Also, if you're on a Debian-based distrib, you should prefer using `adduser` instead of `useradd` which is quite low level.

Comment: I am pretty sure `adduser` is a symlink to `useradd` in RHEL. The upstream for `adduser` in Debian, is actually Debian, so I would consider it Debian-specific.